# How do I enable MySQL / Aurora event scheduler without SUPER privileges?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

We want to use MYSQL events with AWS Aurora if possible.
We have changed the AWS RDS parameter group -- set event_scheduler to ON and rebooted -- but MySQL still shows event scheduler as OFF & will not allow it to be reset.

Comment: Did you create a new parameters group or modify the default? You will need to create and assign a new parameters group and reboot.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work with the new serverless variant as you can only modify a few select cluster parameters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html